# Custom Angular window dependency

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, unit-testing

I am developing an Angular application which resides inside an Android WebView. In order to interact with my Android app, I have exposed an object at window scope:

```
window.MyAndroidApp
```

Which has methods such as:

```
window.MyAndroidApp.doStuff();
window.MyAndroidApp.doOtherStuff();
```

I'm confused as to how I can interact with this object via an Angular controller without referencing it directly, so that I may mock it via unit tests?

```
// How do I define androidFunctions as window.MyAndroidApp so that
// I may mock it for unit testing?
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "androidFunctions", function($scope, androidFunctions) {
    androidFunctions.doStuff();
    androidFunctions.doOtherStuff();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn this into a service - you can then mock it the normal way.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('androidManager', [$window, function ($window) {
   return $window.MyAndroidApp;
});
```

As you are putting it on window it will also be on $window as you can even mock it out that way using something like [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/)

```
sinon.mock($window, 'MyAndroidApp', {
   doStuff: function () {....},
   doOtherStuff: function () {..}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular `$window` service

from docs

A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

```
<script>
  angular.module('windowExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
      $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert(greeting);
      };
    }]);
</script>
```